# How is this lambda function evaluated in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Apologies, I am a total newbie to programming learning Python 3, and I've been stuck at this question
This is the code:

```
f = lambda x, y: lambda z: (x)(y)(z)

result = (f)(lambda x: lambda y: x, lambda z: z * 2)(3)(4)

print(result)
```

Result: 8

I tried to break it down:

`f(lambda x: lambda y:x, lambda z:z*2)(3)(4)` means x refers to `(lambda x:lambda y: x)` and y refers to `(lambda z:z*2)`.

from there, f takes in x and y, and returns a lambda function that expects 1 argument z.

thus, `lambda z: (x)(y)(z) (3)(4)`

(3) is applied to z, returning `(x)(y)(3)(4) => (lambda x:lambda y:x)(lambda z: z*2)(3)(4)`

so, `(lambda x: lambda y:z)` is applied to `(lambda z:z*2)`. is this not just `(lambda z:z*2)`?

why isnt the output `(lambda z:z*2)(3)(4)` with 3 applied to z to return 6?

instead, the output is 8.

I believe my error is in the part where (3) is applied to z, but I can't seem to logic it out.

I don't have anyone else to ask so Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: It might be clearer if you turn the lambdas into regular `def`s...

Answer (score 3):

Break it down by turning each `lambda` into a `def`:

```
def f(x, y):
    def inner(z):
        return x(y)(z)
    return inner

def g(x):
    def inner(y):
        return x
    return inner

def h(z):
    return z * 2

result = f(g, h)(3)(4)
```

That at least makes it possible for you to reason about each individual piece of the expression according to its name:

```
# f(g, h)(z) -> g(h)(z)
# g(h)(z) -> h

# f(g, h)(z)    -> h
# f(g, h)(3)(4) -> h(4)
# f(g, h)(3)(4) -> 4 * 2 -> 8

print(result)  # 8
```

Answer (score 0):

> so, `(lambda x: lambda y:z)` is applied to `(lambda z:z*2)`. is this not just `(lambda z:z*2)`?

No. First, `(lambda x: lambda y:z)` should be `(lambda x: lambda y: x)`, with an `x` instead of the last `z`. Second, evaluating that with argument `lambda z: z*2` gives `lambda y: lambda z: z*2`, not `lambda z: z*2`. Applying `lambda y: lambda z: z*2` with the single argument `3` produces `lambda z: z*2`, and applying that with the single argument `4` produces `4*2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to break out a debugger, you can instrument your function with a decorator that prints out what's happening:

```
from functools import wraps

_level = 0


def wrap_func(f, *, name=None):
    name = name or f.__name__

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args):
        global _level
        print("  " * _level, f"Calling {name!r} with {args!r}")
        _level += 1
        res = f(*args)
        _level -= 1
        print("  " * _level, f" => returned {res!r}")
        return res

    return wrapped


f = wrap_func(lambda x, y: wrap_func(lambda z: (x)(y)(z), name="xyz"), name="xy")

result = f(
    wrap_func(lambda x: wrap_func(lambda y: x, name="y:x"), name="y:x-wrapper"),
    wrap_func(lambda z: z * 2, name="two-multiplier"),
)(3)(4)

print(result)
```

This prints out (which is admittedly pretty cryptic still)

```
 Calling 'xy' with (<function <lambda> at 0x10d2249a0>, <function <lambda> at 0x111dee660>)
  => returned <function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x11207c400>
 Calling 'xyz' with (3,)
   Calling 'y:x-wrapper' with (<function <lambda> at 0x111dee660>,)
    => returned <function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x11207c540>
   Calling 'y:x' with (3,)
    => returned <function <lambda> at 0x111dee660>
  => returned <function <lambda> at 0x111dee660>
 Calling 'two-multiplier' with (4,)
  => returned 8
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code isn't doing any side effects, you can just simplify the expression using the [SICP substitution method](https://youtu.be/V_7mmwpgJHU?t=354). I'll keep away from the numbers at first:

```
f(lambda x: lambda y: x, lambda z: z * 2)
(lambda x, y: lambda z: (x)(y)(z))(lambda x: lambda y: x, lambda z: z * 2)
(lambda z: (lambda x: lambda y: x)(lambda z: z * 2)(z))
(lambda z: (lambda y: lambda z: z * 2)(z))
(lambda y: lambda z: z * 2)
```

These are all the same. In fact I'm verifying this by just testing with application at each step in case I do a mistake. eg. `(lambda z: (lambda x: lambda y: x)(lambda z: z * 2)(z))(3)(4) # => 8`.

We can then continue on the application:

```
(lambda y: lambda z: z * 2)(3)(4) # y is completely ignored
(lambda z: z * 2)(4)
4 * 2
```